# Seems @SuppressWarnings is not considered during compilation

Tags: java

To experiment with `@SuppressWarnings` annotation I have written the following sample program:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Set set = new HashSet();
        Integer obj = new Integer(100);
        set.add(obj);
    }

}
```

But even after this annotation, I get following output on console:

```
Note: Test.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

If I move the annotation just before the main method declaration then warnings are suppressed.
What is missing here?

Thanks.

Comment: `@SuppressWarnings` values depend on the compiler. Eclipse, for example, will use `rawtypes` to suppress raw type warnings.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I use following environment of Java: java version "1.8.0_20"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_20-b26)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.20-b23, mixed mode)

Comment: try "rawtypes". "unchecked" is for unchecked casts (which you don't have).

Comment: But since I am using raw type for collection, it is expected that Java 5 and above will throw warnings at compile time. But I should be able to use @SuppressWarnings to suppress the same, if I am sure that raw type is completely safe to use.

Comment: checked with "rawtypes" and "all" options but it is the same result :(

Comment: The problem is the scope of the suppression. Investigating.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis The specific warning type `unchecked` is defined in the JLS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler tells you to `Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.` Doing so provides the context: while you annotated *the declaration* with `@SuppressWarnings`, you are also calling a generic method as a raw operation.

```
Test.java:9: warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to add(E) as a member of the raw type Set
        set.add(obj);
               ^
  where E is a type-variable:
    E extends Object declared in interface Set
```

If you move the `@SuppressWarnings` to the `main` method as a whole, the warning goes away.

[The JLS section on `@SuppressWarnings`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.6.3.5) says:

> If a program declaration is annotated with the annotation `@SuppressWarnings`[...] then a Java compiler must not report any warning [...] if that warning would have been generated as **a result of the annotated declaration or any of its parts.** (my bold)

Your example code only suppresses the local-variable declaration, not the method declaration.

**Update**

Oddly enough, even the message you got apparently isn't technically a warning but a note. Compiling with `-Werror` works just fine. Using an `-Xlint` option makes it a warning.

Comment: Thanks. This solves the issue. But ideally, warning suppression should happen at lowest possible scope. I thought this annotation could have been put just before raw type method call is made. But it seems this is not possible.

Comment: The idea is to avoid the use of raw types. If you declared `Set<Integer> set = ...` then the annotation is not needed at all.

Answer (score 0):

Following will be the program with no compile time warnings:

```
 import java.util.*;

 public class Test {

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked") 

public static void main(String[] args){

    Set set = new HashSet();

    Integer obj = new Integer(100);

    set.add(obj);

    }

 }
```

Remember this is just for experiment with annotation. Here ideal solution is to use generics instead of raw types.